# MySql return not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

Table: test

```
--------------
| Id | Name  |
--------------
| 1  | Test1 |
| 2  | Test2 |
--------------
```

I want to select Ids not exist like:

```
SELECT search_id 
FROM test 
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4);
```

And return:

```
-------------
| search_id |
-------------
| 3         |
| 4         |
-------------
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Put the values in a table and use a `left join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Not In` operator

```
select Search from (
select 1 Search union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 ) a where Search not in (select Id from test)
```

Or as suggested by Gordon use `left join`

```
SELECT Search
FROM   (SELECT 1 Search
        UNION all
        SELECT 2
        UNION all
        SELECT 3
        UNION all
        SELECT 4) a
       LEFT JOIN youratable b
              ON a.Search = b.Id
WHERE  b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: getting error  


Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks it works, but it won't be too slow if i have a large number of Ids to Union?

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo - if the input is not going to repeat then use `union all` which will have better performance

Comment: I thought in create a temp table and insert the Ids and compareI don't know if it's a good choice

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo am not sure why you are doing this so cannot comment. Use temp table